# using XML and XSL files from Saxon

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd, saxon

The simplicity of `Xalan` is quite appealing, but 
how would I perform [this](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/overview.html) simple transform from `saxon` using `xml` and `xsl` files?

```
package xalan;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class XalanTransform {

    public XalanTransform() {
    }

    public void transform(URI xml, URI xsl, URI out) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xsl)));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(xml)), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File(out))));
    }

}
```

It literally couldn't be simpler, and I appreciate being able to work with files.  I've done some similar operations with `saxon` from the `CLI` but am possibly overlooking similar documentation, for `saxon` with `Java` as above, where the files are loaded at run-time.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to read the Saxon  documentation (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/)? Saxon provides two interfaces, its own s9api, but for compatibility it also implements the JAXP transformation API (which has nothing to do with Xalan but is rather part of previous SUN and now Oracle JRE APIs), so put Saxon 9 on the class path and the above code should run Saxon.

Comment: found https://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml with, I think, the resources bundle.  I'll take a look as I can.

Comment: The download page http://saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml#resources has all examples in the resources zip you can find there, it is also on Sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.9/ and in the repository https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.9/samples/java/he/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you are using is JAXP, and it is supported by Saxon as well as by Xalan: you just need to ensure that Saxon's implementation of TransformerFactory is on the classpath.

It's true that this API is simple, but for some purposes it is too simple. For example:

- It doesn't support XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 features such as schema awareness, streaming, multiple output documents
- It doesn't allow parameters to be supplied with the full range of data types
- It doesn't provide any way to supply the same document as input to multiple transformations (you can try supplying it as a DOM, but that's a very poor fit to XSLT, and it's not even thread-safe)

For these reasons Saxon also provides it's own API called s9api. It's a little bit more complex for doing very simple things, but it's much more comprehensive and powerful.